# Objective C: How to grab a number after a sub string from string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I have a lengthy string as below

> Please plan to attend to provide upgrade to existing code
>
> morning meeting to acoomdate bum team members
>
> Meeting Number: 457 231 123
>
> ---
>
> ### To join this meeting
>
> 1. go to http://domainname.com
> 2. enter password

Now i want to grab number after the text "Meeting Number"
i.e. 457 231 123

Any help please.
thanks

**EDIT**

Lets say i have a string

```
NSString *myString = @"Please plan to attend to provide upgrade to existing code morning meeting to acoomdate bum team members  Meeting Number: 457 231 123 ----------------------------------------------------- to join this meeting ------------------------------------------------------  1. go to http://domainname.com 2. enter password"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use regular expressions to capture the numbers also (assuming that there is only numeric characters and spaces in the result, and there is always the "Meeting Number: " prefix):

```
NSString *text = @"Please plan to attend to provide upgrade to existing code\nmorning meeting to acoomdate bum team members\nMeeting Number: 457 231 123\nTo join this meeting\n\ngo to http://domainname.com\nenter password";
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"Meeting Number: ([0-9 ]+)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:text
                                  options:0
                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, [text length])];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    NSRange matchRange = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
    NSString *result = [text substringWithRange:matchRange]; // Here is the result
}
```

this can be used to parse multiple inputs together since we have a loop here. If the requirements is just to parse one input, replace the code after the declaration of the regex with:

```
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:text
                                                options:0
                                                  range:NSMakeRange(0, [text length])];
if (match) {
    NSRange matchRange = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
    NSString *result = [text substringWithRange:matchRange];
}
```

Comment: Wow, this worked brilliantly
i have one more question
if i want to search for strings like "Meeting Number" or "Meeting #" or "Meeting ID",  do i need to call it three times or we can add all in a single regex?

Comment: I think you can use a single regex, something like `@"Meeting (Number|#|ID): ([0-9 ]+)"`, then change the parameter of `rangeAtIndex:` from 1 to 2 accordingly, and use the for loop version of code to get all of the number strings.

Comment: Wow, worked like Charm

Thanks Thanks Thanks a lot for this code.

Answer (score 3):

You want [NSScanner](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It's there specifically for this sort of thing.

```
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:yourString];
NSString *prefix = @"Meeting number: ";
NSString *numbers;
[scanner scanUpToString:prefix intoString:NULL];
[scanner scanString:prefix intoString:NULL];
[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] intoString:&numbers];
// numbers now contains the numbers you want.
```

(This can be trivially adapted to find any number by doing `scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]` instead of the two lines with the prefix string.)

Comment: numbers returning everything after Meeting Number:
i.e. numbers now has value like this
numbers are 457 231 123-----------------------------------------------------to join this meeting ------------------------------------------------------1. go to http://domainname.com 2. enter password

But i want only 457 231 123

Comment: @cnu: In your post, there is a newline at the end of the line. Is there not in the actual material? Because I just tried it with the text you gave and it worked.

Comment: @chunk now i added an NSString to give full idea, please look into it.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Might be you can use something like -

```
NSCharacterSet *nonNumberSet = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];
int numberValue = [[@"Meeting Number: 457 231 123" stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:nonNumberSet] intValue];
```

Edit - 
For all numbers -

```
NSCharacterSet *nonNumberSet = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];
int numberValue = [[[@"Meeting Number: 457 231 123" componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:nonNumberSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""] intValue];
```

Comment: Thanks for that but its returning only 457 not all numbers i.e. 457 231 123

Comment: wow,its working now but i need some more help
i want the text which is right after string "Meeting Number" in whole string i wrote above.
can you help me with that too
Thanks

Comment: Whether the text will always be like "Meeting Number: ---" or it can be changed. If it is always going to be same then it is quite easy. Else we have to look for some other solution.

Comment: seems like your issue is fixed now?

Answer (score 0):

This will do it (with very little generality):

```
NSRange promptRange = [bigString rangeOfString:@"Meeting Number: "];
NSRange numberRange = NSMakeRange(promptRange.location + promptRange.length, 11);
NSString *answer = [bigString substringWithRange:numberRange];
```

Comment: Hello, this is working but it assumes we have 11 characters always but i want something like this
if you see a non digit other than space stop

Answer (score 0):

take into string just like

```
NSString *str = @"Meeting Number: 457 231 123";
```

seperated by your string

```
NSArray *theList = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
NSString *getStr = [theList objectAtIndex:1];
[getStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

Comment: This can fail if string changes a bit only.

Comment: @RIP agree with your comment. but if string is remain same then this may be help him

Comment: Yes, that's true. This is solution with less generality link danh's answer.

Comment: as RIP said, i want to gather number which is after Meeting Number from whole string, 
But thanks for taking your time to help me.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, if you want one number:

```
static int ReadMeetingNumber(NSString * string) {
    // ARC:
    // locate the line
    NSString * const prefix = @"Meeting Number: ";
    NSMutableString * meetingNumberLine = nil;
    for (NSString * line in [string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]]) {
        if ([line hasPrefix:prefix]) {
            meetingNumberLine = [line mutableCopy];
        }
    }

    if (nil == meetingNumberLine) {
        return nil; 
    }
    // trim and get int value
    [meetingNumberLine deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, prefix.length)];
    [meetingNumberLine replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, meetingNumberLine.length)];
    return meetingNumberLine.intValue;
}
```

---

This should do it, if you want to locate the *individual* numbers:

```
// ARC:
// Returns an NSArray of NSNumbers
static NSArray * ReadMeetingNumbers(NSString * string) {
    // locate the line
    NSString * const prefix = @"Meeting Number: ";
    NSMutableString * meetingNumberLine = nil;
    for (NSString * line in [string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]]) {
        if ([line hasPrefix:prefix]) {
            meetingNumberLine = [line mutableCopy];
        }
    }

    if (nil == meetingNumberLine) {
        return nil; 
    }

    [meetingNumberLine deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, prefix.length)];

    // locate the numbers:
    NSMutableArray * results = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (NSString * at in [meetingNumberLine componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]) {
        const int   intValue = at.intValue;
        if (0 != intValue) {
            [results addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:intValue]];
        }
    }
    return [results copy];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish the above task by scanning all the numbers in the above string using the following code.

```
NSString * inputString = @"Please plan to attend to provide upgrade to existing code morning meeting to acoomdate bum team membersMeeting Number: 457 231 123To join this meeting go tohttp://domainname.comenter password"; // Your input string 
NSString * subStr = [inputString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange([inputString rangeOfString:@"Meeting Number:"].location, 27)];
NSString *number = [[subStr componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""]; // Scans all numbers from input string
NSLog(@"%@",number); // Your required output printed in console
```

Comment: Yes but it returns all other numbers which are not after the string "Meeting Number: "

Comment: I have edited the code to meet your requirement.You can check it now.