# Regex to grab a number from within a string

Tags: iphone, ios, regex

I would like to grab a number from a string.

The string is:  `"responseID: 1 is the return value";`

Sometimes the number could be 1, or 3, 300, 3000...

I am trying to do this in objective C for the iphone.

I've tried `NSPredicate` and `NSRegularExpression`, but I can not seem to get the right regex to start with.

I tried `"*[0-9]+*"`;

Does this return the "1" , "300" or whatever number to me when I call the regex?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I was able to search again and found exactly what I was looking for:  see this:
[Objective C: How to grab a number after a sub string from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291881/objective-c-how-to-grab-a-number-after-a-sub-string-from-string?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

`\d+` should match 1 or more digits.